# Ruby xml to xls style error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, excel

Hi as you can see below I am using ruby to automate an xls creation process, but unfortunately when the xls document is created a small style error occurs. This shows in the checkboxes where the first few are too big as you can see in the image below.
[image]

also here is the code of the xls table:

```
<table border="1" width="100px">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th colspan="32">Hours of rest record</th>
    <th colspan="16">Crew Members Name</th>
    <th colspan="1"></th>
    <th colspan="2"><%= @crewmember.user.full_name %></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th colspan="48">Work hours (Place and 'x' in each half hour worked and count hours of rest)</th>
    <th colspan="1">Start Date</th>
    <th colspan="2"><%= @shifts.first.day %></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="1">Hours / date</th>
    <th colspan="2">0030</th>
    <th colspan="2">0130</th>
    <th colspan="2">0230</th>
    <th colspan="2">0330</th>
    <th colspan="2">0430</th>
    <th colspan="2">0530</th>
    <th colspan="2">0630</th>
    <th colspan="2">0730</th>
    <th colspan="2">0830</th>
    <th colspan="2">0930</th>
    <th colspan="2">1030</th>
    <th colspan="2">1130</th>
    <th colspan="2">1230</th>
    <th colspan="2">1330</th>
    <th colspan="2">1430</th>
    <th colspan="2">1530</th>
    <th colspan="2">1630</th>
    <th colspan="2">1730</th>
    <th colspan="2">1830</th>
    <th colspan="2">1930</th>
    <th colspan="2">2030</th>
    <th colspan="2">2130</th>
    <th colspan="2">2230</th>
    <th colspan="2">2330</th>
    <th colspan="1">Hours of rest</th>
    <th colspan="2">Comment</th>
  </tr>
  <% @shifts.each do |shift| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= shift.day %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_0000_to_0029 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_0030_to_0059 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_0100_to_0129 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_0130_to_0159 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_0200_to_0229 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_0230_to_0259 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_0300_to_0329 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_0330_to_0359 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_0400_to_0429 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_0430_to_0459 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_0500_to_0529 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_0530_to_0559 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_0600_to_0629 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_0630_to_0659 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_0700_to_0729 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_0730_to_0759 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_0800_to_0829 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_0830_to_0859 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_0900_to_0929 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_0930_to_0959 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_1000_to_1029 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_1030_to_1059 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_1100_to_1129 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_1130_to_1159 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_1200_to_1229 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_1230_to_1259 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_1300_to_1329 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_1330_to_1359 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_1400_to_1429 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_1430_to_1459 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_1500_to_1529 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_1530_to_1559 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_1600_to_1629 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_1630_to_1659 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_1700_to_1729 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_1730_to_1759 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_1800_to_1829 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_1830_to_1859 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_1900_to_1929 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_1930_to_1959 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_2000_to_2029 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_2030_to_2059 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_2100_to_2129 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_2130_to_2159 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_2200_to_2229 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_2230_to_2259 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_2300_to_2329 %></td>
    <td><%= shift.hour_2330_to_2359 %></td>

    <td colspan="1" style="text-align:center;"><%= shift.hours_of_rest %></td>
    <td colspan="2"><%= shift.time_profile_id %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

<br/><br/>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Approved By:</th>
    <th>Hours of Rest Record:</th>
    <th>Version</th>
    <th>Last Review</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br/>

<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Crew Member Signiture</td>
    <td style="width:200px; border-bottom: 0.5px dotted black"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Master Signiture</td>
    <td style="width:200px; border-bottom: 0.5px dotted black"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

another note is that when I remove all the tables but the very top table it seems to fix it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: When you ask a question about a code, it's really important to provide a minimal sample of that code, plus input and output data to replicate the problem. Your question would have been closed very quickly because it only shows the output of the code which we couldn't use to help diagnose the problem. It might help you to review the Help sections of the site so you're more familiar with how to ask questions.

Comment: @theTinMan Hi thank you, I will keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys I figured it out the "Hours of rest record", "version", and "last view" was dictating the width